# Socket IO broadcast to room not working

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

This really stumps me, Im trying to create a multi room chat application using node and socket.io and for some reason, the web socket event is not firing for user created rooms. I have the following code:

```
        if (clientData.messageRoom == "Lobby") {
            socket.broadcast.to('').emit('sendMessageResponse', data);
        }
        else {
            console.log("broadcast room: " + clientData.messageRoom);
            socket.broadcast.to(clientData.messageRoom).emit('sendMessageResponse', data);
        }
        console.log('user ' + name + ' send this : ' + clientData.messageBody + " to room: " + clientData.messageRoom);
```

And I have the following logs on the server

```
List of all rooms: 
{ '': [ 'WrCg6zlmUOJgXlcX0oW5', 'Ym4FCRTqRoGw5nbo0oW6' ],
  '/SF': [ 'Ym4FCRTqRoGw5nbo0oW6', 'WrCg6zlmUOJgXlcX0oW5' ] }
broadcast room: SF 
   debug - broadcasting packet
user Davis send this : test to room: SF 
broadcast room: SF 
   debug - broadcasting packet
user Bob send this : se to room: SF 
   debug - broadcasting packet
   debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"sendMessageResponse","args":[{"message":"dfd","username":"Bob","roomName":"Lobby"}]}
user Bob send this : dfd to room: Lobby
```

You can see that a web socket event was fired when Bob sends a message "dfd" to Lobby but not to a user created room. I'm getting the list of all rooms with

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms);
```

And clearly the two connected clients' ids are in both room Lobby and SF, so the event should be fired for room SF, but it's not! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I am using socket.io version 0.9.16

Comment: You dont have two rooms according to log, which you say to be `SF` and `Lobby`. It is just messageRoom property of recieved message. Emit is not working because there is no `Lobby`.

Comment: Please rerun the test and post the results.

Comment: { '': [ 'WrCg6zlmUOJgXlcX0oW5', 'Ym4FCRTqRoGw5nbo0oW6' ],
  '/SF': [ 'Ym4FCRTqRoGw5nbo0oW6', 'WrCg6zlmUOJgXlcX0oW5' ] }

is the list of all rooms, so yes I do have 2 rooms, a room with no name '', and '/SF', my question is that you can see that I broadcast to that room, but the "websocket writing 5..." log message is not firing

Answer (score 0):

you should try **delete io.sockets.manager.rooms[''];**

By default all the users get connected to this '' room.

Deleting this room would allow users to connect to the user created rooms.

Comment: OK What if I don't want to delete the rooms? Can't a user connect to the default room and other rooms as well?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Doesn't work. Still has same behavior as above

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem, somehow a space found it's way on to the end of my roomnames, So no packets were actually being send because it couldn't find the room in the hash. To prevent others from suffering the same fate, make sure the room names match up!